# Javascript doesn't work in first load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, turbolinks

I'm use jquery UI datepicker and have a problem. My datepicker don't work in first load. I searched and try substitute document.ready for windows.load, but don't work too :/
My code is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  alert('carregado!')   
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', language: 'pt-BR', autoclose: true});
  $('#status_bar').barrating( {
    onSelect: function(value, text) {
      $('#projeto_status').val(value);
    }
  });
});
```

I see others answers, but no one work with me. 
A observation, my project is in rails 4, and I use [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/)

Comment: Please elaborate _"don't work"_. On closer inspection, you might just be missing a `;` after the 2nd line.

Comment: try $(document).ready

Answer (score 2):

YES! Thanks! I got it!

I chance the function, look:

```
var do_on_load = function(){
  alert('carregado!')   
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', language: 'pt-BR', autoclose: true});
  $('#status_bar').barrating( {
    onSelect: function(value, text) {
      $('#projeto_status').val(value);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(do_on_load)
$(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load)
```

Now, resolved!! :D

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to ensure that all of your scripts are being loaded properly and you aren't experiencing any errors related to them.

You'll need to make sure that you are loading the necessary jQuery scripts and jQueryUI scripts (in that order) and that your datepicker() function isn't being called prior to those scripts being loaded :

```
<!-- Related jQuery and jQueryUI scripts and CSS -->
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Place any scripts related to your barrating plugin here -->

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //Shorthand for $(document).ready(){ ... }
  $(function(){
    alert('carregado!')   
    //Your DatePicker
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', language: 'pt-BR', autoclose: true});
    //Ensure that you are closing each of these properly
    $('#status_bar').barrating({
         onSelect: function(value, text) {
              $('#projeto_status').val(value);
         }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**[Example](http://jsbin.com/uqesam/1/edit)**